# Using CSS to make a <li> two rows tall?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have a set of records that I display with a formview and then page through one at a time. Several of the fields have lengths that vary wildly, and often cause the fields to wrap onto a second row. Currently as you page through the records, the visual appearance of the formview changes based on the length of those fields, and the wrapping causing the page to get taller and shorter in turn. I'm not really a big fan of the page dimensions changing, and so would like to fix that.

Here is what I currently have for the css:

```
.CommitmentInfo
{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  float:left;
  list-style:none;
}
    .CommitmentInfo li
    {
      width: 300px;
    }
    .CommitmentInfo li.b
    {
      width: 150px;
    }
```

Then the code it's being used with:

```
<ol class="CommitmentInfo">
  <li><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# "<b>Vendor Name:</b>" + 
      Eval("ven_name") %>' /></li>
  <li><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# "<b>Stock Item:</b>" + 
      Eval("cmt_stock_code") %>' /></li>
  <li><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# "<b>Item Description:</b>" +
      Eval("inv_description") %>' /></li>
</ol>
<ol class="CommitmentInfo">
  <li><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# "<b>Agent Name:</b>" + 
      Eval("cmt_agent") %>' /></li>
  <li><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# "<b>Sales Rep:</b>" + 
      Eval("slm_name") %>' /></li>
  <li><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# "<b>Documentation:</b>" +
      GetDocument(Eval("doc_description"), Eval("cmt_document")) %>' /></li>
</ol>
<ol class="CommitmentInfo">                    
  <li class="b"><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# "<b>Qty Changed:</b>" + 
      Eval("cmt_changed", "{0:d}") %>' /></li>
  <li class="b"><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# "<b>Last Update:</b>" + 
      Eval("cmt_added", "{0:d}") %>' /></li>  
</ol>
```

There are three columns from three lists. The elements that need to be double-row are the first and third of the first column, and the third of the second column. I'm thinking the solution would be to apply a new class to those particular list elements, but I haven't been able to find anything for making list elements a fixed number of rows. Suggestions?

Comment: I don't know what your page looks like, but try (1) don't use fixed width (at least not in pixels) and (2) try changing ``line-height`` of the particular elements?

Comment: Theorizing here:  There isn't per-say a way to set a number of rows on an LI like you could set a number of columns in a table cell with colspan for example.  But, to fashion something ourselves.  If you give the LI's a height of 2em, that would be the height of two lines of text dependent on the pixel size of your text.  so 2em of a font that is 12px would be 24px.  This doesn't account for line height, but you could calculate that in and come up with a number of roughly 2.5em?

Comment: I would recommend looking at something like `height: 2em;`. This will set the height to 2 lines high

Comment: Erica: The reason for the column width is because I want the layout to be very specific (I'm converting this from what used to be a set of tables), and setting the width is necessary for the three columns to exist side-by-side in the formview without the third column wrapping below.

@Michael, I ended up going with that approach and it worked perfectly, thank you. Post that as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Glad it worked, answer posted below. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential solution would be to use EM's for a height as the EM unit is based off font size.

So the theory here is that if you have one line of text and font size is 12px tall, then 1em = 12px.

By setting the height of the LI to 2em you are effectively making the height 24px, or two lines worth of height.  That said, this doesn't take into account line-height, if we have a lineheight of say 15px, that's 3px per line of extra space for a total of 6, 24+6=30=2.5em

Answer (score 4):

I looked into something similar for the height, and found that a combination of dropping the text into a `div`, putting a `max-height` on it and turning the `overflow` off worked for me.

Comment: Just to add to this - it can be a bit fiddly to get the exact height sometimes, so I would recommend using a `px` line-height if you're going to and work in multiples of this.